# R and corrections of models with AR(q) errors

Tags: r

Does anyone know if there is a package to estimate corrected models where the error process is AR(q), that is a more general Prais-Winsten method?

Comment: A finite distributed lag model, for example... It is in a teaching context where the students are not required to program as such, simply use built-in or packaged functions... The procedure they learn is described in Wooldridge's introductory text, ch. 12.